# invalid Product Id's in In App Purchases iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

i just created **In App Purchases** for my new application and checked **Cleared for Sale** option.
But when i test my application after 2 days its still giving me **invalid product id's**..
I didnt ***Approve*** them earlier. Do i need to approve the App Purchases too before testing them...Will that affect my application when i upload my final binary and apple starts testing it??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

It turned out I had to increment the version number of my app in my bundle. This was an app already on sale on the app store for which we decided to add in-app purchase.

Also make sure your bundle Id matches the one in iTunes Connect.

You don't need to approve the in-app purchase to test it only to clear it for sale.